# XSLT sum Income amount based on Income Type

Tags: xml, xslt, sum, grouping

I am new to XSLT. I have the following XML source structure:

**INPUT XML:**

```
<BORROWER _SSN="*********">
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BASE" _MonthlyTotalAmount="25000.0000" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BASE" _MonthlyTotalAmount="25000.0000" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BONUS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="COMMISSIONS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="OVERTIME" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
</BORROWER>
<BORROWER _SSN="*********">
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BASE" _MonthlyTotalAmount="1000.0000" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BONUS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="25000.0000" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BONUS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="10.0000" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="COMMISSIONS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="OVERTIME" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
</BORROWER>
```

I need to sum MonthlyTotalAmount amount based on IncomeType.

I tried the below code. But it is not working.

**My Code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:util="http://www.aaa.com/Schema/aaa/BTUtility"
                        xmlns:quan="http://www.aaaa.com/Schema/aaa"
                xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//quan:REQUEST_GROUP"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//quan:REQUEST_GROUP">
    <LOAN_APPLICATION>
      <xsl:variable name ="SSN" select ="./REQUEST/KEY[@_Name = 'Test_SSN']/@_Value"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="./REQUEST/REQUEST_DATA/LOAN_APPLICATION/BORROWER">
        <BORROWER>          
          <xsl:for-each select="./CURRENT_INCOME">
            <CURRENT_INCOME>
              <xsl:if test="not(userCSharp:IsBlankOrNull(userCSharp:TrimString(string(./@IncomeType))))">
                <xsl:attribute name="IncomeType">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="userCSharp:ToUpperText(./@IncomeType)= 'BASE'">
                      <xsl:text>Base</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="userCSharp:ToUpperText(./@IncomeType)= 'BONUS'">
                      <xsl:text>Bonus</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="userCSharp:ToUpperText(./@IncomeType)= 'COMMISSIONS'">
                      <xsl:text>Commissions</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>                    
                    <xsl:when test="userCSharp:ToUpperText(./@IncomeType)= 'OVERTIME'">
                      <xsl:text>Overtime</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="not(userCSharp:IsBlankOrNull(userCSharp:TrimString(string(./@_MonthlyTotalAmount))))">
                <xsl:attribute name="_MonthlyTotalAmount">
                  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(./@_MonthlyTotalAmount, '#0.00')"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
            </CURRENT_INCOME>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </BORROWER>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </LOAN_APPLICATION>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output needed similar to below:**

```
<BORROWER _SSN="*********">
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="Base" _MonthlyTotalAmount="5000.00" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="Bonus" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.00" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="Commissions" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.00" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="Overtime" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.00" />
</BORROWER>
<BORROWER _SSN="*********">
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="Base" _MonthlyTotalAmount="1000.00" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="Bonus" _MonthlyTotalAmount="25010.00" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="Commissions" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.00" />
    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="Overtime" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.00" />
</BORROWER>
```

Any small help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can read about Muenchian's grouping. BTW, `5000.00` isn't the right sum of the inputs you've provided. Please revisit.

Comment: How important is the case of `IncomeType` and the formatting of `_MonthlyTotalAmount`?

Comment: @BenL I need to avoid repeated IncomeType and sum the repeated one

Comment: Please improve your post. Both your input and output are malformed XML - and you posted only a fraction of your XSLT code, post a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you take a **well-formed input** such as:

```
<root>
    <BORROWER _SSN="*********">
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BASE" _MonthlyTotalAmount="25000.0000" />
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BASE" _MonthlyTotalAmount="25000.0000" />
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BONUS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="COMMISSIONS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="OVERTIME" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
    </BORROWER>
    <BORROWER _SSN="*********">
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BASE" _MonthlyTotalAmount="1000.0000" />
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BONUS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="25000.0000" />
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BONUS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="10.0000" />
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="COMMISSIONS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
        <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="OVERTIME" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0.0000" />
    </BORROWER>
</root>
```

and apply the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="BORROWER">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="CURRENT_INCOME" group-by="@IncomeType">
                    <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="{@IncomeType}" _MonthlyTotalAmount="{sum(current-group()/@_MonthlyTotalAmount)}" />
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <BORROWER _SSN="*********">
      <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BASE" _MonthlyTotalAmount="50000"/>
      <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BONUS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0"/>
      <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="COMMISSIONS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0"/>
      <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="OVERTIME" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0"/>
   </BORROWER>
   <BORROWER _SSN="*********">
      <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BASE" _MonthlyTotalAmount="1000"/>
      <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="BONUS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="25010"/>
      <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="COMMISSIONS" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0"/>
      <CURRENT_INCOME IncomeType="OVERTIME" _MonthlyTotalAmount="0"/>
   </BORROWER>
</root>
```

Formatting the number is a trivial addition.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already have for-each at BORROWER. So I got this error "xsl:for-each-group' cannot be a child of the 'BORROWER' element", when I implement your code.

Comment: @PalaniKumar I don't understand what your XSLT code is trying to accomplish. Earlier, you had a `group-by` attribute on an `xsl:for each` - so I assumed you were using an XSLT 2.0 processor. Are you, in fact, using an XSLT 2.0 processor? If not, the above answer will not work for you, and you will have to use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) instead.

Comment: Looks like this xslt is generated by BizTalk (userCSharp namespace). It must use the XSLCompiledTransform class in .NET which is an XSLT 1.0 processor.